# Printing logs between date range where date in format i.e-"13-Oct-2022 12:00"

Tags: shell, date, awk, scripting, audit

My log file looks like this:

```
01-Nov-2022 10:13:36 CDOTCEM CLI: USER=root            COMMAND=configure_system_firewall no                                                                              
01-Nov-2022 10:13:38 CDOTCEM sudo:      root : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/root ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/iptables --policy OUTPUT ACCEPT                                     
01-Nov-2022 10:13:38 CDOTCEM sudo:      root : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/root ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/iptables --policy INPUT ACCEPT                                      
01-Nov-2022 10:13:38 CDOTCEM sudo:      root : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/root ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/iptables -F                                                         
01-Nov-2022 10:13:38 CDOTCEM sudo:      root : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/root ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/iptables-save                                                       
01-Nov-2022 10:14:21 CDOTCEM CLI: USER=root            COMMAND=configure_system_ntp_server 192.168.1.98 12.1.4.2                                                         
01-Nov-2022 10:14:21 CDOTCEM sudo:      root : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/root ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/rm /tmp/1.dmp                                                            
01-Nov-2022 10:14:21 CDOTCEM sudo:      root : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/root ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/rm /tmp/1.dmp                                                            
01-Nov-2022 10:14:26 CDOTCEM CLI: USER=root            COMMAND=configure_system_apply_configuration                                                                      
01-Nov-2022 10:14:29 CDOTCEM sudo:      root : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/root ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/sbin/reboot                                                                  
01-Nov-2022 10:14:29 CDOTCEM sshd[27216]:  pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user root                                                                          
01-Nov-2022 10:14:29 CDOTCEM sshd[27216]:  pam_warn(sshd:setcred): function=[pam_sm_setcred] service=[sshd] terminal=[ssh] user=[root] ruser=[<unknown>] rhost=[192.168.2
01-Nov-2022 10:14:57 CDOTCEM: SELF-TEST Passed                                                                                                                           
01-Nov-2022 10:15:19 CDOTCEM ipsec_starter[12235]:  Starting strongSwan 5.7.2-nistpqc IPsec [starter]...                                                                 
01-Nov-2022 10:15:20 CDOTCEM ipsec_starter[12306]:  charon (12310) started after 820 ms                                                                                  
01-Nov-2022 10:28:13 CDOTCEM: SELF-TEST Passed                                                                                                                           
31-Oct-2022 10:31:07 CDOTCEM ipsec_starter[7199]:  Starting strongSwan 5.7.2-nistpqc IPsec [starter]...                                                                  
31-Oct-2022 10:31:07 CDOTCEM ipsec_starter[7273]:  charon (7278) started after 520 ms                                                                                    
31-Oct-2022 11:58:50 CDOTCEM sshd[13011]:  PAM unable to dlopen(/lib/security/pam_cracklib.so): /lib/security/pam_cracklib.so: cannot open shared object file: No such fi
31-Oct-2022 11:58:50 CDOTCEM sshd[13011]:  PAM adding faulty module: /lib/security/pam_cracklib.so                                                                       
31-Oct-2022 11:58:50 CDOTCEM sshd[13011]:  PAM _pam_init_handlers: no default config /etc/pam.d/other                                                                    
31-Oct-2022 11:58:53 CDOTCEM sshd[13057]:  pam_warn(sshd:auth): function=[pam_sm_authenticate] service=[sshd] terminal=[ssh] user=[root] ruser=[<unknown>] rhost=[192.168
31-Oct-2022 11:58:53 CDOTCEM sshd[13057]:  pam_unix(sshd:account): account root has password changed in future
```

I want to print logs that are in between two dates specified by user. The log file is not sorted. Kindly suggest any way. awk command is not working correctly

I tried using awk command but it is giving wrong output

```
awk '$0>=from&&$0<=to' from="$start date" to="$end_date" auditfile
```

It gives wrong output if file is not sorted.

Comment: i'll give you a hint - **rephrase** the dates as `YYYYMMDD` - this form retains proper comparison ordering both numerically and as a `8-character ASCII string` - you don't need a full epochs conversion for it

Comment: Since you want to print lines between 2 dates your example would have been more useful for testing with if it contained more than just 2 dates and you added the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

- update 1 : had to add strange string-coercion at the `substr()` to work around `nawk` compatibility issue - now it's working on `gawk`, `mawk-1`, `mawk-2`, and `nawk`

————

```
function __(_) {  #  input - Eng. month names, any casing, min. 3 letters
                  # output - MM : [01-12], zero-padded
    return \
    ((_=toupper(_)) ~ "^[OND]" ? "" : _<_) \
    int(index("=ANEBARPRAYUNULUGEPCTOVEC", substr(_ "",_+=_^=_<_,_))/_)
}
```

The reference string might look odd at first -

> `the 2nd + 3rd letters of month names constitute a unique set`

The `dd` and `yyyy` components are already in the needed form, so with this function, one could make `YYYYMMDD` without running it through `mktime()`, `strftime()`, or both

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    beg = fmt(beg)
    end = fmt(end)
}
{ cur = fmt($1) }
(beg <= cur) && (cur <= end)

function fmt(date,      d,mthNr) {
    split(date,d,/-/)
    mthNr = (index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",d[2])+2)/3
    return sprintf("%04d%02d%02d", d[3], mthNr, d[1])
}
```

```
$ awk -v beg='10-Oct-2022' -v end='05-Nov-2022' -f tst.awk file
01-Nov-2022 10:13:36 CDOTCEM CLI: USER=root            COMMAND=configure_system_firewall no                                                    
01-Nov-2022 10:13:38 CDOTCEM sudo:      root : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/root ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/iptables --policy OUTPUT ACCEPT           
01-Nov-2022 10:13:38 CDOTCEM sudo:      root : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/root ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/iptables --policy INPUT ACCEPT            
01-Nov-2022 10:13:38 CDOTCEM sudo:      root : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/root ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/iptables -F                               
01-Nov-2022 10:13:38 CDOTCEM sudo:      root : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/root ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/iptables-save                             
01-Nov-2022 10:14:21 CDOTCEM CLI: USER=root            COMMAND=configure_system_ntp_server 192.168.1.98 12.1.4.2                               
01-Nov-2022 10:14:21 CDOTCEM sudo:      root : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/root ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/rm /tmp/1.dmp                                  
01-Nov-2022 10:14:21 CDOTCEM sudo:      root : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/root ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/rm /tmp/1.dmp                                  
01-Nov-2022 10:14:26 CDOTCEM CLI: USER=root            COMMAND=configure_system_apply_configuration                                            
01-Nov-2022 10:14:29 CDOTCEM sudo:      root : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/root ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/sbin/reboot                                        
01-Nov-2022 10:14:29 CDOTCEM sshd[27216]:  pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user root                                                
01-Nov-2022 10:14:29 CDOTCEM sshd[27216]:  pam_warn(sshd:setcred): function=[pam_sm_setcred] service=[sshd] terminal=[ssh] user=[root] ruser=[<unknown>] rhost=[192.168.2
01-Nov-2022 10:14:57 CDOTCEM: SELF-TEST Passed                                                                                                 
01-Nov-2022 10:15:19 CDOTCEM ipsec_starter[12235]:  Starting strongSwan 5.7.2-nistpqc IPsec [starter]...                                       
01-Nov-2022 10:15:20 CDOTCEM ipsec_starter[12306]:  charon (12310) started after 820 ms                                                        
01-Nov-2022 10:28:13 CDOTCEM: SELF-TEST Passed                                                                                                 
31-Oct-2022 10:31:07 CDOTCEM ipsec_starter[7199]:  Starting strongSwan 5.7.2-nistpqc IPsec [starter]...                                        
31-Oct-2022 10:31:07 CDOTCEM ipsec_starter[7273]:  charon (7278) started after 520 ms                                                          
31-Oct-2022 11:58:50 CDOTCEM sshd[13011]:  PAM unable to dlopen(/lib/security/pam_cracklib.so): /lib/security/pam_cracklib.so: cannot open shared object file: No such fi
31-Oct-2022 11:58:50 CDOTCEM sshd[13011]:  PAM adding faulty module: /lib/security/pam_cracklib.so                                             
31-Oct-2022 11:58:50 CDOTCEM sshd[13011]:  PAM _pam_init_handlers: no default config /etc/pam.d/other                                          
31-Oct-2022 11:58:53 CDOTCEM sshd[13057]:  pam_warn(sshd:auth): function=[pam_sm_authenticate] service=[sshd] terminal=[ssh] user=[root] ruser=[<unknown>] rhost=[192.168
31-Oct-2022 11:58:53 CDOTCEM sshd[13057]:  pam_unix(sshd:account): account root has password changed in future
```